# console available data but i find that say undefined

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, console

```
    console.log(data.result)
    console.log(data)
    console.log(e)
```

[image: response code]

[image: console]

response code

But whenever I run my script, I receive console undefined but i don't understand why say undefined  :

[image]

Comment: You are probably on the wrong scope. Try `window.data` or check if `window` is accessible

Comment: script.js.:74 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'result' of undefined
    at HTMLFormElement.progress (script.js.:74)

Comment: same error say undefined

Comment: So `undefined` is for `data.result`, so `result` is not a key on `data`. Click on `>` on logged `data` to see all available keys.

Comment: I HAVE SEEN RESULT IS A KEY OF DATA

Answer (score 0):

Normally, I am always got this error. 
My issue is the variable sometime have a data, but sometime the data was missing or the data be a null.

So, you need confirm the variable source is correct.

When you call " progress: function(e, data) ", you must be provide e & data have a value.

[image]

data: FormData {}  <-- It has not any data. So you will got Undefined Message.
And I cannot see Variable e. <-- So, So you will got Undefined  Message again.

Normally, I will checking the data source and take action.

```
e.g. 
progress: function(e, data) {
  if (e === null) { return; }
  if (data === null) { return; }
...
```

Above method, If nothing data, don't do anything.

You may be another way

```
e.g.
progress: function(e, data) {

change to
progress: function(e = '', data = {result:''})  {
```

Above method for setting default value, If nothing data, using default value

Comment: i have find all key just not find result

Comment: i have change method and same to your method but error is not change

Comment: Please check call function method is correct or not. Sometime incorrect call method, it can not past the the data value. Specially, Ajax data.

Comment: Can you post how to call method coding here?

Comment: e, data  <- How come the source data?

Comment: ajax progress response

Comment: I think your problem is come form AJAX progress. Because AJAX is Async send out data. So, you did not get the data in your program.

Comment: If you want get the AJAX data in a variable and than call function, that would not work.

Comment: Because AJAX need a time for get data. So, we call that is Asynchronous get data.
You need using AJAX progress push data to your variable. But you would not know when will complete.